# zsh make **/*.cpp **/*.cxx **/*.hpp not result in error

Tags: zsh, glob

I have "v" aliased to "vim **/*.cpp **/*.hpp **/*.cxx"

Problem is, if I'm in a directory without any *.cxx files, zsh treats this as an error. Is there anyway to tell zsh to create the absence of **/*.cxx files as "" instead of an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
set -o NULL_GLOB
```

Another variation that may be of interest is:

```
set -o CSH_NULL_GLOB
```

They work slightly different when all the patterns fail to expand.  When at least one pattern successfully expands, the two are the same.  But if none of the patterns expand, `NULL_GLOB` will still run the command while `CSH_NULL_GLOB` will return an error.